# Reactjs PWA - iOS on opening Progressive Web App Second time - Camera does not work

Tags: ios, reactjs, camera, progressive-web-apps

Reactjs PWA.

1) Added site through Safari by pressing "Add To Home Screen".

2) App opens up in a standalone and can open the camera fine on first load.

3) If I move out of and back into the app, the camera is black and cannot take a photo.

4) If I clear the app from the background and reopen, the camera works again.

ios 13.1.2

Picking a file from the camera roll also works fine.

```
<input type="file" id="files" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onChange={this.onFileSelected} style={{display: 'none'}}/>
```

There is no log from the console. I am guessing that when it opens again it doesn't give the app permissions for the camera.

Camera works every time in safari itself.

Comment: Got the same problem. I tried to solve this with document.addEventListener('visibilitychange'= to check the change and tried rerender the camera-componen after changet, but without effect.

Comment: Experimenting exact same behavior here.